# How can I concatenate columns and sum values from two data frames in Julia?

Tags: julia, julian-date

I have two data frames (left data frame is 1, the other is 2) and I want to get the final data frame based on the below conditions:

1.Group Col2 by Col1, for example, A 566,788,888,999,1212

2.In data frame 2, I can find that the (Group A) 788,888,999,1212 so I want to keep it, while 566 is not in data frame 2, so ignore it.

3 Sum Total for all members in Data Frame 1 and 2, for example, A-788(2), A-888(3), A-999(4), A-1212 (5), 788-888(12), 999-1212 (13), so 2+3+4+5+12+13 = 39

```
Col1    Col2  Total        Col3   Col4   Total  
 A      566    1            788   888      12
 A      788    2            999   1212     13
 A      888    3            700   707      14
 A      999    4            701   702      15
 A      1212   5
 B      700    6
 B      701    7
 B      702    8
 B      703    9
 B      704    10
 B      705    11
```

Expected Result

```
ResultCol1    ResultCol2           ResultTotal
  A           788,888,999,1212        39
  B           700,701,702             50
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is this what you want?

```
using DataFrames

m1 = ["A"      566    1
      "A"      788    2
      "A"      888    3
      "A"      999    4
      "A"      1212   5
      "B"      700    6
      "B"      701    7
      "B"      702    8
      "B"      703    9
      "B"      704    10
      "B"      705    11]

m2 = [788   888      12
      999   1212     13
      700   707      14
      701   702      15]

df1 = DataFrame(m1, [:Col1, :Col2, :Total])
df2 = DataFrame(m2, [:Col3, :Col4, :Total])
df1f = filter(x -> x.Col2 in df2.Col3 || x.Col2 in df2.Col4, df1)
df3 = by(df1f, :Col1) do x
          DataFrame(Col2=Tuple(x.Col2), Total=sum(x.Total))
      end
for r3 in eachrow(df3), r2 in eachrow(df2)
    if any(in.([r2.Col3, r2.Col4], [r3.Col2]))
        r3.Total += r2.Total
    end
end
```

And now `df3` holds data you have asked for. I have not optimized it for performance - is execution speed relevant for you?